# Unicode terminal lock symbol

Tags: internationalization, unicode

Is there a character for the below key symbol that you can copy and paste?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the closest one in the Unicode specification, but there's few fonts that support it as it's a relatively new addition:

**'SQUARED KEY' (U+26BF)**  <sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26bf/browsertest.htm
- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26bf/fontsupport.htm

Answer (score 2):

Not identical to that, but emoji has several lock & key symbols

available from 'Show Emoji & Symbols' if you have System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard > 'Show Keyboard, Emoji & Symbol viewers in menu bar' enabled.

[image]

Comment: ahh, never thought to search 'key', ty :)  I found two, in fact - will add to answer

Comment: @grgarside The roll-back to the old version makes it almost invisible in Google Chrome - at least for me: I only see some blanks and a square

Comment: @klanomath I tested in Safari, Google Chrome and Google Chrome Canary before rolling back and both versions work fine, but Tetsujin had a H1 which made them larger. Feel free to roll back again though.